# Grab all input data with Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, post, input

Im trying to post input data with angular, but I don't know how to grab the data from the input fields.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">

    <div class="page-header"><h1>Testar</h1></div>

    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine, 'has-success' : userForm.name.$valid }">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Fel namn</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine, 'has-success' : userForm.username.$valid && !userForm.username.$pristine}">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">För kort</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">För långt</p>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine, 'has-success' : userForm.email.$valid && !userForm.email.$pristine}">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Ange korrekt e-post</p>
        </div>      

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
as.controller('Test', function($scope, $http, $rootScope)
    {   

        $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
            if(isValid) 
            {   
                $http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', {"data": $scope.userForm})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(data, status) {

                });
            }

        };
    });
```

A post is made when I hit the button, but the data that Is being sent looks like this:

```
{"data":{"name":{},"username":{},"email":{}}}
```

How can I take the data from all the input fields? Should I refer to userForm as I do in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create one more $scope object - at beginning it will be empty:

`$scope.form = {};`

Every field will be a part of this object:

`<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="form.name" required>`

After send all fields you will have in object **$scope.form**.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/QjNd6/

Comment: You welcome : ) I have one more suggestion – you can disable send button until all fields will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

you have ng-model variables in scope:

```
$scope.name
$scope.user.username
$scope.email
```

you can all of these prefix with user. and then send with ajax $scope.user instead of $scope.userForm

or

try to send object which is copied by: angular.copy($scope.userForm)

Comment: How do you mean? Can I concate all this variables into one object, and then send the object containing the data with $http.post?

Comment: try to rewrite `$http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', {"data": $scope.userForm})` with `$http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', {"data": angular.copy($scope.userForm)})` or i think better solution is: change in HTML `ng-model="name"` to `ng-model="user.name"` the same with email input and then send through $http.post like this: `$http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', {"data": angular.copy($scope.user)})`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property in your scope, say `user`. Have all your `ng-model` values be `user.SOMETHING`. This way you can easily send the `$scope.user` holding all the data, as in `{data: $scope.user }`.